# cocos2d - repeated scrolling background has an annoying joining line

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use a vertically scrolling background. I have an image which is of double the height of the screen. The image is a plane blue image (seamless). However, during scrolling
a thin blackline persist at the position where the images are joined while scrolling.

I have used the normal offset mechanism to achieve endless scrolling.

Can somebody please help me remove this patch of line?
image is attached.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
myImage.scaleY=1.01f;
```

It usually works, find the right value for your case, maybe 1.05, maybe 1.001.

Comment: scaling introduces even more artifacts (filtering), I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Used this a hundreds times, works perfectly. Depends on the case, but for a simple background like this, that's the easiest solution to implement, and that will work perfectly. I recommend it in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your backgrounds to .5 pixel locations. Update positions every frame to be at a .5 coordinate, for example (20.5, 100.5).

Alternative is to have the background images overlap by 1 pixel.

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D. I'll try that as well.